# G1 young GC does not free memory - to-space exhausted

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm using G1GC, jdk 1.7

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_79-b15), built on Apr 10 2015 11:34:48 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
Memory: 4k page, physical 32826020k(12590436k free), swap 33431548k(33358800k free)

CommandLine flags: -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=3000000 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:InitialHeapSize=10737418240 
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1073741824 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000 
-XX:MaxHeapSize=10737418240 
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC
```

Mostly minor GC works fine, but it still start unusual fullGC, about one to two times in an hour.

This is a normal case young GC log

```
3443.100: [GC pause (young), 0.3021260 secs]
  [Parallel Time: 277.6 ms, GC Workers: 4]
  [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 3443100.5, Avg: 3443100.6, Max: 3443100.6, Diff: 0.1]
  [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 2.9, Avg: 3.0, Max: 3.1, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 11.9]
  [Update RS (ms): Min: 33.5, Avg: 33.6, Max: 33.9, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 134.5]
     [Processed Buffers: Min: 180, Avg: 204.8, Max: 227, Diff: 47, Sum: 819]
  [Scan RS (ms): Min: 76.0, Avg: 76.2, Max: 76.3, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 304.9]
  [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.3]
  [Object Copy (ms): Min: 164.4, Avg: 164.4, Max: 164.5, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 657.7]
  [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
  [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.2]
  [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 277.3, Avg: 277.4, Max: 277.4, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 1109.5]
  [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 3443377.9, Avg: 3443378.0, Max: 3443378.0, Diff: 0.0]
  [Code Root Fixup: 0.2 ms]
  [Code Root Migration: 0.3 ms]
  [Clear CT: 2.0 ms]
  [Other: 22.1 ms]
  [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
  [Ref Proc: 15.7 ms]
  [Ref Enq: 0.5 ms]
  [Free CSet: 3.2 ms]
  [Eden: 5996.0M(5996.0M)->0.0B(5648.0M) Survivors: 148.0M->196.0M Heap: 8934.5M(10.0G)->2997.2M(10.0G)]
  [Times: user=1.13 sys=0.00, real=0.30 secs]
```

And this is a unusual GC log before the fullGC.
It repeated two to three times, and it didn't clean any memory.

```
3482.422: [GC pause (young) (to-space exhausted), 3.4878580 secs]
[Parallel Time: 1640.5 ms, GC Workers: 4]
  [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 3482421.8, Avg: 3482422.4, Max: 3482424.0, Diff: 2.2]
  [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 2.1, Avg: 3.2, Max: 3.8, Diff: 1.7, Sum: 12.6]
  [Update RS (ms): Min: 104.8, Avg: 105.2, Max: 105.6, Diff: 0.8, Sum: 421.0]
     [Processed Buffers: Min: 201, Avg: 221.2, Max: 236, Diff: 35, Sum: 885]
  [Scan RS (ms): Min: 75.1, Avg: 75.2, Max: 75.3, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 300.8]
  [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.2]
  [Object Copy (ms): Min: 1455.9, Avg: 1456.1, Max: 1456.2, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 5824.2]
  [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 0.4]
  [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
  [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 1638.2, Avg: 1639.8, Max: 1640.4, Diff: 2.2, Sum: 6559.3]
  [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 3484062.2, Avg: 3484062.2, Max: 3484062.2, Diff: 0.0]
[Code Root Fixup: 0.2 ms]
[Code Root Migration: 0.5 ms]
[Clear CT: 2.0 ms]
[Other: 1844.7 ms]
  [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
  [Ref Proc: 60.1 ms]
  [Ref Enq: 0.5 ms]
  [Free CSet: 1.2 ms]
[Eden: 5648.0M(5648.0M)->0.0B(1876.0M) Survivors: 196.0M->172.0M Heap: 9441.9M(10.0G)->9352.3M(10.0G)]
[Times: user=9.29 sys=0.05, real=3.49 secs]
```

Then it started a fullGC

```
3490.812: [Full GC 9626M->1879M(10G), 7.6059670 secs]
[Eden: 0.0B(2048.0M)->0.0B(6144.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 9626.3M(10.0G)->1879.5M(10.0G)], [Perm: 33901K->33901K(36864K)]
[Times: user=10.24 sys=0.00, real=7.61 secs]
```

Why the last youngGC didn't clean any memory?

Comment: I don't know details of the jvm7 gc, but in general a young generation gc will fail to collect if there are many pointers from the older generation into the younger one, even if those pointers lie in garbage in the old gen. It's impossible for an algorithm to determine when this is happening with certainty. One way it's done is to watch what's recovered in successive young gen collections and trigger a full collection when the results of the young gen collections are poor. It's likely that's what's happening here. Once the old garbage is freed, the young can follow.

Comment: some of your parameters might be constraining G1's heuristics too much. are you sure they are necessary? also, what are you goals, low pause time or high throughput? also, you should update to java 8. G1GC was still had a lot of problems under java 7.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are suffering from evacuation failures as can be seen by the `to-space exhausted` part of the start message for the collection.

This occurs when there is not enough free space on your heap to promote survived or promoted objects (or both) and the heap can not be expanded more.

Monica Beckwith writes the following in [Tips for Tuning the Garbage First Garbage Collector](http://www.infoq.com/articles/tuning-tips-G1-GC)

> For G1 GC, an evacuation failure is very expensive -
>
> - For successfully copied objects, G1 needs to update the references and
>     the regions have to be tenured.
> - For unsuccessfully copied objects, G1
>     will self-forward them and tenure the regions in place.

Often G1 can't keep up with the allocation rate when forced to do these operations and will eventually be forced to a full GC due to allocation failure. This is probably why you see a full GC after a couple of evacuation failures.

Monica also writes about possible solutions in [Garbage First Garbage Collector Tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html)

> - Increase the value of the -XX:G1ReservePercent option (and the total
>     heap accordingly) to increase the amount of reserve memory for
>     "to-space".
> - Start the marking cycle earlier by reducing the
>     -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent.
> - You can also increase the value of the -XX:ConcGCThreads option to
>     increase the number of parallel marking threads.

Also, increasing the heap is another option that would reduce the likelihood of evacuation failures.

Comment: When we increase the G1ReservePercent why do we also need to increase the total heap? Is it because the percentage increase needs to translate into absolute space? It seems kind of counter intuitive because it seems like G1Reserve space would increase in absolute terms by just increasing total heap.

Comment: @MoizRaja If you increase the `G1ReservePercent` without increasing the heap, more memory will be kept in reserve and hence less memory will be available to your application than before. To compensate, the total heap needs to be increased. You are correct in that increasing the total heap will also increase the reserve. So if you both increase `G1ReservePercent` and the heap, you will get an increase in reserve space from both operations.